# force https for few domains ot of all using htaccess but all domains shared same files

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have setup system so all different domains used the same files and separate content or product based on the store id assigned to each domain.

Now I want to force only 2 domains to use https for all pages using httaccess.

Say, I have 5 domains abc.com, qwe.com, xyz.com, rty.com & uio.com

now I want abc.com & xyz.com to force https, not for other domains.

How I will rewrite rules for this in htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(abc|xyz)\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
```

in the htaccess in your document root.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your case:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
```